# Delete Calendar tab in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I wanna delete or hidden (without CSS display method) Tabs of [Month] [Year] [Week] [Day] on Calendar module in Drupal 7.

I attached an image of this:

[image]

Anybody knows how to delete it? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is an option in the page settings of the calendar view for showing the menu items or not! You can check the type "no menu entry" for each tab and it is hidden!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the tab tamer module http://drupal.org/project/tabtamer .As this module will help you in hiding or deletion of the tab.